# List view back to top postion after updating data in arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that refreshed every 5 secs, using a XML parsing. After refreshing, the current position of the list go back to first position. Is there any possible ways to solve this?

Comment: Please tell us how you're refreshing the listview.

Comment: Probably you clear list data and set all new. You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html scrollTo(int, int) method

Comment: @flo 

`public void TimerMethod() {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi this is piyush",
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    parse(link);
    setAdapter();
   }
  });    `
call this method every 5sec. parse() using for xml parsing and setAdapter() for seting new values to listadapter

Answer (score 5):

By using setAdapter() to update a list Android resets the position. Try altering the Adapter instead.

I don't know which adapter you're using so here two examples.

ArrayAdapter

```
adapter = list.getAdapter();
if (adapter == null) {
    // Create new adapter + list.setAdapter()
} else {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(newData);
    adapter.notify(notifyDataSetChanged());
}
```

CursorAdapter

```
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Here I am using ArrayAdapter. But I didn't get "list" you mentioned above.

Comment: list stands for the ListView you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `lv.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)` where pos could be any int, preferably the length of the adapter, if you want the listview to *autoscroll* to the last added entry as it is refreshed.

```
public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position) 


Smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position. The view will scroll such that the indicated position is displayed.
```

Comment: For my case, this was the only option that would actually work even once notifyDataSetChanged() had fired.

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you out....

```
// get position of listview
int index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// notify dataset changed or re-assign adapter here

//re-assign the position of listview after setting the adapter again
listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```